# Sub linear Jotto solver (algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, game-theory

I'm trying to implement a Jotto solver. [Here](https://codingbat.com/prob/p245250) is a description of the game of Jotto (just read the beginning). Here is the problem I want to solve:

You are given:

- a dictionary of valid English words (all of length 5 and with unique characters)
- a secret word to guess, of 5 unique characters (present in the dictionary)
- a function returning you the **size** of the intersection between the guess and the secret word (number of characters in common).

Find a valid word with the same characters as the secret word. Again, all words are of length 5. All words have unique characters.

I'm struggling to find a sublinear solution. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: What is your solution so far?

Comment: linear scan over dictionary words. If we have N words in our dictionary this would represent at most N calls to `get_intersection_with_secret` which is constant time as the size of the words is fixed. So overall O(N).  But for every guess, we get potential clues we could use to subdivide the space. I'm just not sure on how to use those, as well as the proper structure we would need to build to access subspaces of the dictionary in sublinear time.

Comment: First you will have around 10000 words in your dictionary and there are `26!/(26-5)! = 7893600` permutations of 5-letter words with unique letters.
So what about modifying one letter at a time and see whether the intersection increases or stay the same or decreases?

Comment: All guesses need to be in the dictionary. You cannot submit "qwert" as a guess if it is not in the dictionary.

Comment: Correct... however for a correct set of 5 letters there are only `5! = 120` permutations to search in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If you can preprocess offline, you can build a [BK-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree) on the words in the dictionary using the symmetric difference metric (i.e., d(A, B) = |A - B| + |B - A|, which will be five minus the function value). Then you can use the function to traverse the BK-tree in the obvious manner.

Comment: And I guess the size of this tree is the size of the dictionary. Isn't this solution still worst case linear as the tree is not necessarily balanced?

Comment: @user3091275 Yes